# RNA folding at specific temperature with ViennaRNA in python

Tags: python, rna, secondary-structure

I am trying to get dot-bracket-notations of single stranded RNA via the ViennaRNA python package (https://pypi.org/project/ViennaRNA/) at different temperatures. I have read in the docs (https://www.tbi.univie.ac.at/RNA/ViennaRNA/doc/html/examples_c.html) that the folding prediction at different temperatures is possible with C..but nowhere it is described how to specify the temperature when using python. Does anyone know how to specify the temperature at which the RNA folding is predicted with the ViennaRNA package in python?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I think that the "Global Variables" section of the [docs](https://www.tbi.univie.ac.at/RNA/ViennaRNA/doc/html/wrappers.html) describes this:

> For the Python interface(s) SWIG places global variables of the C-library into an additional namespace cvar. For instance, changing the global temperature variable thus becomes

```
RNA.cvar.temperature = 25
```

Globals are somewhat surprising to me as a way of handling this. It seems like you should be able to specify this differently. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Very cool, thanks.